# MonoTouch + SQLite + SQLite.Net ORM: Full Text Indexing

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios, full-text-search

I use the [SQLite.NET](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) ORM wrapper for SQLite on [MonoTouch](http://Xamarin.com) to create a database based on business objects. Works fine.

I wish to run the SQLite `full text indexing command` so that a full text virtual table is created. However the [SQLite.Net ORM](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) doesn't support that directly. Is there a way to create an index using other commands on MonoTouch?

The SQL to create a Full Text Index is just:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "Term" USING FTS3 (
"Id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
"Word" integer,
"Definition" TEXT 
);

insert into Term(Id,Word,Definition) 
  Select Id,Word,Definition from SomeOtherTable;

drop table SomeOtherTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that SQLite.NET does not supports creating full text indexes, but supports creating ordinary indexes.

Anyway, you could try to execute any custom SQL-code via:

```cs
<YOUR_SUBCLASS_OF_SQLiteConnection>.Execute(<YOUR_SQL_CODE>);
```

Example:

```
public class LocalDatabase: SQLiteConnection
{
    ...
    public LocalDatabase (string path) : base(path)
    {
        ...
        Execute("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE \"MyTable\" USING FTS3 ...");
        ...
    }       
    ...
}
```